# How to override inner objects with mapstruct @MappingTarget while uisng NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE

Tags: jhipster, mapstruct

I am trying to convert a DTO into an object to do a partial update.
my mapper looks like this:

```
    @Named("partialUpdate")
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void partialUpdate(@MappingTarget Product product, ProductDTO productDTO);
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( dto.getDefaultSupplier() != null ) {
            if ( entity.getDefaultSupplier() == null ) {
                entity.defaultSupplier( new Supplier() );
            }
            supplierDTOToSupplier1( dto.getDefaultSupplier(), entity.getDefaultSupplier() );
        }
```

the issue with this code is that it tried change the is of a persisted entity. I would prefered the code to no check if the inner object `defaultSupplier` was null, juste create a new one. And set the id... correctly like this...

```
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( dto.getDefaultSupplier() != null ) {
            // no null check
            entity.defaultSupplier( new Supplier() );
            supplierDTOToSupplier1( dto.getDefaultSupplier(), entity.getDefaultSupplier() );
        }
```

or just:

```
product.setDefaultSupplier(supplierDTOToSupplier(productDTO.getDefaultSupplier()))
```

with supplierDTOToSupplier handling the logic.

Is there a way to achieve this without manual code ?

EDIT:
Workaround:

```
    @Named("partialUpdate")
    @Mapping(target = "defaultSupplier", expression = "java(supplierDTOToSupplier( dto.getDefaultSupplier() ))")
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void partialUpdate(@MappingTarget Product product, ProductDTO dto);
```

I suspect this only works because I have a default mapper like this:

```
    Product toEntity(ProductDTO dto);
```